# Changing color of a div (alternate rows)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div which loops dynamically. What I want is every new row should have alternate color i.e first row's div bg will be lets say white and second row's div bg will have grey as the background.

Here's the html

```
<div class="container serchcntent"> <!-- bg color change in his div-->
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                  <div class="serbg">
                      <div class="serhead">Institute</div>
                      <span class="institute_name">Yak Group</span>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                  <div class="serbg">
                      <div class="serhead">Date</div>
                      <span class="start_date">08/Feb/2017</span>
                      <div class="subheadsp"><span class="duration">2Days</span></div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                  <div class="serbg">
                      <div class="serhead">Place</div>
                      <span class="venue">Mubai</span>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 ss">
                  <div class="serbg">
                      <div class="serhead">Course Fee</div>
                      <span class="fee"></span>
                      <div class="subhead"></div>
                      <a href="" class="book_now" batch-id="">Book Now</a>
                  </div>
              </div>

          </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You don't need any JS for this, just CSS. `:nth-child(odd)` and/or `:nth-child(even)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for you. You will get alternate color for row.

```css
.col-md-3 {
      background: #fff;
  }
  .col-md-3:nth-child(2n) {
      background: #ccc;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container serchcntent"> <!-- bg color change in his div-->
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
          <div class="serbg">
              <div class="serhead">Institute</div>
              <span class="institute_name">Yak Group</span>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
          <div class="serbg">
              <div class="serhead">Date</div>
              <span class="start_date">08/Feb/2017</span>
              <div class="subheadsp"><span class="duration">2Days</span></div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
          <div class="serbg">
              <div class="serhead">Place</div>
              <span class="venue">Mubai</span>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 ss">
          <div class="serbg">
              <div class="serhead">Course Fee</div>
              <span class="fee"></span>
              <div class="subhead"></div>
              <a href="" class="book_now" batch-id="">Book Now</a>
          </div>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess I didn't explained properly, my query is the entire container loops and its becomes a new row below the first container. Can we give a class to the container and then use css? any idea how to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

You can do using `:nth-child(odd)` or `:nth-child(even)` selector

```css
.serchcntent {
      background: #fff;
  }
.serchcntent:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container serchcntent"> <!-- bg color change in his div-->
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
          <div class="serbg">
              <div class="serhead">Institute</div>
              <span class="institute_name">Yak Group</span>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
          <div class="serbg">
              <div class="serhead">Date</div>
              <span class="start_date">08/Feb/2017</span>
              <div class="subheadsp"><span class="duration">2Days</span></div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
          <div class="serbg">
              <div class="serhead">Place</div>
              <span class="venue">Mubai</span>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 ss">
          <div class="serbg">
              <div class="serhead">Course Fee</div>
              <span class="fee"></span>
              <div class="subhead"></div>
              <a href="" class="book_now" batch-id="">Book Now</a>
          </div>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="container serchcntent"> <!-- bg color change in his div-->
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
          <div class="serbg">
              <div class="serhead">Institute</div>
              <span class="institute_name">Yak Group</span>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
          <div class="serbg">
              <div class="serhead">Date</div>
              <span class="start_date">08/Feb/2017</span>
              <div class="subheadsp"><span class="duration">2Days</span></div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
          <div class="serbg">
              <div class="serhead">Place</div>
              <span class="venue">Mubai</span>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 ss">
          <div class="serbg">
              <div class="serhead">Course Fee</div>
              <span class="fee"></span>
              <div class="subhead"></div>
              <a href="" class="book_now" batch-id="">Book Now</a>
          </div>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

or

```css
.color {
  background:grey
}
.color:nth-child(even) {
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="color">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
</div>

<div class="color">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
</div>

or

<div class="color">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
</div>

<div class="">
div without color class

</div>
```

Comment: I guess I didn't explained properly, my query is the entire container loops and its becomes a new row below the first container. Can we give a class to the container and then use css? any idea how to achieve that

Comment: so you need to container has odd even row? right? Update my answer for container looping odd even

Comment: No, what I want is, lets say <div class="color"> ..anything.. </div>, what I want is when the entire div is looped the new div will be added, that divs color will be grey. alternate color white and grey. Hope I am clear

Comment: yes this is what I wanted but both the rows are coming in grey.

Comment: when you want grey row just add `.color` class in that div...

Comment: this div loads dynamically. so I want it to change color automatically every time.